# Trigger to ensure, that date1 must be smaller than date2

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I creating my first database in Oracle. I have in table two columns with date of begin and date of end and I need to ensure, that `date2`(date of end) isn't smaller than `date1`(date of begin).
I think that it's possible to do this with a trigger, but I don't know how to write this trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think that it's possible to do it with some trigger

You *can* do this in a trigger, but a `CONSTRAINT` is easier:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
(
    ADD CONSTRAINT valid_dates CHECK (date2 >= date1) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats even better